# How to split byte array and assign to a byte variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, split, byte

In my C# Application, I have a byte array as follows.

```
byte[] byteArray = {0x2, 0x2, 0x6, 0x6};
```

I need to split the first two elements i.e 0x2 and 0x2 and assign it to a byte variable. Similarly last two elements should be assigned to another byte variable.

i.e

```
byte FirstByte = 0x22;
byte SecondByte = 0x66;
```

I can split the array into sub arrays but I am not able find a way to convert byteArray into a single byte.

Comment: So each byte in the array contains only a nibble, correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just bitwise OR them together, shifting one of the nibbles using `<<`:

```
byte firstByte  = (byte)(byteArray[0] | byteArray[1] << 4);
byte secondByte = (byte)(byteArray[2] | byteArray[3] << 4);
```

You didn't specify the order in which to combine the nibbles, so you might want this:

```
byte firstByte  = (byte)(byteArray[1] | byteArray[0] << 4);
byte secondByte = (byte)(byteArray[3] | byteArray[2] << 4);
```